# How to define the font color for a specific XLAbel[i] in teechart 7.12

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, teechart

How can I define the `Color` for a specific `XLabel[i]`?

like this,

```
Chart1.Series[0].XLabel[idxMP].FONT.Color := clBLue;
```

but this does not work.

I have Delphi 7 and Teechart 7.12

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. _does not work_ is not a good description of what's happening to you. It does not compile? compiles but raises an exception at runtime? no exception, but no effect? You must be more accurate to describe your problem in order to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

First one is using standard labels and should be done as shown here:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Series1.FillSampleValues(20);
  Series2.FillSampleValues(20);
  Chart1.BottomAxis.OnDrawLabel := DrawBottomAxis;
end;

procedure TForm1.DrawBottomAxis(Sender:TChartAxis; var X,Y,Z:Integer; var Text:String;
  var DrawLabel:Boolean);
var
  lValue: Integer;
begin
  lValue := StrToIntDef(Text, -1);
  if lValue < 0 then
    Sender.LabelsFont.Color := clRed
  else
  if ((lValue mod 2) = 1) then
    Sender.LabelsFont.Color := clGreen
  else
    Sender.LabelsFont.Color := clYellow;
end;
```

Second one is using custom labels as in this code snippet:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
    dt: TDateTime;
    myColor: TColor;
begin
  Chart1.AddSeries(TLineSeries.Create(Self));

  for i:=0 to 10 do
  begin
    dt:=Now + i;
    Chart1[0].AddXY(dt, random, DateToStr(dt));
  end;

  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Items.Clear;

  for i:=0 to Chart1[0].Count-1 do
  begin
    if i mod 2 <> 0 then
      myColor:=clRed
    else
      myColor:=clBlack;

    Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Items.Add(Chart1[0].XValue[i], Chart1[0].Labels[i]).Format.Font.Color:=myColor;
  end;

  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.LabelsAngle:=90;
end;
```

Comment: This is not an answer; it's a comment to the original question. Answers should contain enough content to remain valid even if the referenced off-site links are unavailable for some reason, and yours will be meaningless in that case. Links to external sites are great as additional references, but the answer should be fully stand-alone. (Answers containing only off-site links are also not searchable by future readers of this site trying to locate solutions to problems they're having.) The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) has more details about what constitutes an answer.

Comment: @KenWhite ok, I have updated my answer with the code mentioned on the links I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot!
But ONLY this line is correct: (without Format)

Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Items.Add(Chart1[0].XValue[i], Chart1[0].Labels[i]).Font.Color:=myColor;

But it works now fine!
Thanks